# Can you create apps and custom tabs on a business page?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I've read on several forums and various other videos that you cannot create custom tabs or apps on a simple business page. Several people have asked this question on here, saying that they are redirected back to their page instead of to the developer platform, but they haven't been answered!! Is this correct, that you simply cant do it? If so, what is the answer for businesses who have pages that they want to utilize? Do you have to create an actual user account for your company? Can you link it to your existing page? I've been asking this question all week and no one will respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for, if I understand your question :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Don't ever create a user account for a company, pages are good and practical.

EDIT : You need be someone to create a facebook app, with a user account that will become the app's admin. Then you can add the app to any page you administrate.

Comment: Yeah this is what I am looking for. But when I try to get onto the developer app, it simply redirects me to my page. Ive tried several link, several varying ways to get to the developer app but always get sent back to my page. As a result Ive been reading around and found a lot of people saying that tabs/apps simply cannot be made on business pages. You HAVE to do it through a user account. So although you say dont do it, it doesnt seem as though I have a different option :(

Comment: Come on dudes....someone must know the answer to this?!?!